# why do I get this error if I return value using questionmark operator in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, return

I just tried to return the value using questionmark operator instead of using return twice. But I got an error "Cannot read property 'omitDescription' of undefined" .

```
buttonText() {
  return this.omitDescription ? 'プロフィールをもっと見る' : 'プロフィールを閉じる'
  // return function() {
  //   if(this.omitDescription) {
  //     return 'プロフィールをもっと見る'
  //   } else {
  //     return 'プロフィールを閉じる'
  //   }
  // }
}
```

The part where I commented out did work instead, so I could not figure out the difference.
Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling `buttonText()`?

Comment: where is `buttonText` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the same, in the previous approach you return an function. Try it like this:

```
buttonText() {
    return () => this.omitDescription ? 'プロフィールをもっと見る' : 'プロフィールを閉じる';
}
```